# What changes a subviews frame between viewWillAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, subview

It's a pretty simple setup and the log is confusing me:

I have a UIViewController-subclass. Nothing special. Its view has a subview. I wanted to do some animations on the transform to scale the view. During debugging I found this:

```
----- VIEWDIDLOAD <UIView: 0x9d77bc0; frame = (10 57; 300 206)...
----- VIEWWILLAPPEAR <UIView: 0x9d77bc0; frame = (10 57; 300 206)...
----- VIEWWILLLAYOUTSUBVIEWS <UIView: 0x9d77bc0; frame = (10 57; 460 206)...
----- VIEWDIDLAYOUTSUBVIEWS <UIView: 0x9d77bc0; frame = (10 57; 460 206)...
----- VIEWDIDAPPEAR <UIView: 0x9d77bc0; frame = (10 57; 460 206)...
```

The frame of this subview changes between the call of -viewWillAppear and -viewWillLayoutSubviews. I would expect the frame of the subview to change between -viewWillLayoutSubviews and -viewDidLayoutSubviews.

What happens here between willAppear and willLayout?

Xcode 4.5.1, iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact answer but you should be able to find out by subclassing the view and implementing an override of `setFrame:` that just calls the one in its `super`.  Set a breakpoint and look at the call stack.